# Selectively active/deactivate gzip for specific resources in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, gzip

I'm using Spring Boot 2.5 and I'm trying to enable GZIP for specific resources (controllers) only. I've managed to enable gzip for *all* resources by adding this to my `application.properties` file:

```
server.compression.enabled=true
server.compression.mime-types=text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript,application/javascript,application/json
server.compression.min-response-size=1024
```

But this is not what I want to do. I want to active it only for "/stuff/*", "/example" and "/something/*", and not for other paths.

I've also tried adding a `FilterRegistrationBean` myself:

```java
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<CompressingFilter> compressingFilterRegistrationBean() {
    FilterRegistrationBean<CompressingFilter> registration = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
    registration.setFilter(new CompressingFilter());
    registration.addUrlPatterns("/stuff/*", "/example", "/something/*");
    registration.setName(CompressingFilter.class.getSimpleName());
    registration.setAsyncSupported(true);
    return registration;
}
```

but this seems to have no effect, all resources are still gzipped afaict (`CompressingFilter` is imported from `com.github.ziplet.filter.compression`. So my question is, how can I selectively active gzip compression?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this myself. First, I disabled gzip compression in my `application.properties` file (by removing everything with `server.compression`). Secondly, I upgrade to the latest version of the [ziplet](https://github.com/ziplet/ziplet) filter, at the time of writing this was 2.4.1 (previously we had used 2.0.0). Lastly, I added the remaining configuration to the `FilterRegistrationBean`:

```java
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<CompressingFilter> compressingFilterRegistrationBean() {
    FilterRegistrationBean<CompressingFilter> registration = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
    registration.setFilter(new CompressingFilter());
    registration.setInitParameters(Map.of(
                "includeContentTypes", "text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript,application/javascript,application/json",
                "compressionThreshold", "1024")
        );
    registration.addUrlPatterns("/stuff/*", "/example", "/something/*");
    registration.setName(CompressingFilter.class.getSimpleName());
    registration.setAsyncSupported(true);
    return registration;
}
```